# String operations and memory management

Tags: c++, string, memory-management, char, type-conversion

I want to write a convenient wrapper to a C-style function [strftime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/strftime/). And I've come to some options to convert char-array to string and vise-versa. Here is my code:

```
std::string Time::getAsFormattedString ( const std::string& format , const size_t& maxStringSize = 999 )
{

    char* timeArray = 0;
    std::string timeString;

    //  [OPTION_0]
    timeArray = reinterpret_cast <char*> (malloc(sizeof(char)*maxStringSize)));

    //  [OPTION_1]
    timeArray = const_cast <char*> (timeString.c_str());

    //  [OPTION_2]
    timeArray = &(*(timeString.begin()));

    strftime(timeArray,maxStringSize,format.c_str(),&this->time);
    timeString = timeArray;

    //  [OPTION_0]
    free(timeArray);

    return timeString;

}
```

№0 option looks safe since no exceptions can be thrown before memory freeing (Edit: `timeString = timeArray` can throw one, try-catch needed around that line)

№1 const-casting always looks like a hack

№2 seems to be the best by I do not know if there could be some issues with it

Can you please tell me, which one is the most safe, correct, optimal and maybe kind of best-practice.

Thank you.

Comment: In C++11, at least, just keep the `std::string` and pass it everything before the null terminator.

Comment: @chris excuse me, I did not get your point...

Comment: Sort of like option 2, but, as jalf said, `&timeString[0]` and it's only guaranteed to work in C++11 and if `strftime` does not overwrite the null terminator of the string's data. I'm saying kill `timeArray` and just pass `&timeString[0]`. Also, kill `maxstringsize` and use the string's `size()` function. Then you can guarantee it won't overrun the buffer.

Comment: @chris could you please tell me, why will not it work in c++03?

Comment: Because internal string data is not guaranteed to be contiguous.

Answer (score 3):

None of the options you propose are really acceptable; the
second and the third won't even work.  Globally, there are two
"acceptable" solutions.

The simplest is:

```
char buffer[ 1000 ];
size_t n = strftime( buffer, sizeof( buffer ), format.c_str(), &time );
if ( n == 0 ) {
    throw SomeError;    //  or you might just abort...
}
return std::string( buffer );
```

This has the advantage of simplicity, but you do have to 
document the maximum size as a constraint in your interface.
(It seems like a reasonable constraint to me.)

Alternatively, you can remove the constraint:

```
std::vector<char> buffer( 100 );
size_t n = strftime( &buffer[0], buffer.size(), format.c_str(), &time );
while ( n == 0 ) {
    buffer.resize( 2 * buffer.size() );
    n = strftime( &buffer[0], buffer.size(), format.c_str(), &time );
}
return std::string( buffer.begin(), buffer.begin() + n );
```

(In C++11, and in practice in C++03, you can do this with
`std::string` directly, rather than `std::vector`.  In which
case, you need to call `resize( n )` on the resulting string
before returning it.)

Comment: Could you please tell me will the #0 be correct if I wrap `timeString = timeArray;` in try-catch?

Comment: @Kolyunya #0 is technically correct.  It's just awkward and overly complex for what it does.  If you accept an upper limit on the number of characters generated, then just declare a `char[]` statically.

Answer (score 2):

As a start, the only option that isn't going to crash is option 0 here. The others will crash as you are saying you have allocated 999 bytes but infact the internal string will probably only have 1 byte allocated to it, and sad things will happen.

However I would probably do this by allocating a large chunk of characters on the stack here.

```
char timeArray[2048];
strftime(timeArray,2048,format.c_str(),&this->time);
return string(timeArray);
```

This way you don't have to do any casting or dynamic allocations and will almost certainly be neater and faster.

Comment: With C++11, that concern is eliminated with `std::string`'s guarantee of contiguous memory. In previous versions, it's still one line to make a vector you can use from the string. Both can be the size you need and no more.

Comment: @chris: The reason for the char array is that the final size needed isn't available until after the `srftime` call - `std::string`'s guarantee of contiguous memory doesn't help there.

Comment: @JoeGauterin, Ah, woops, I'm used to having the size available. At least it's still easy enough to resize a bit bigger if it didn't all fit.

Answer (score 1):

Option 2 (or better still, `&timeString[0]`) should be preferred.

You're right about the `const_cast` being bad in option 1, and in option 0, you could, at the very least, clean up the code a bit by using `new` instead of `malloc` (and avoid the cast)

But prefer option 2.

(Oh, and as commenters have pointed out, if you're writing into the string itself, you obviously have to first resize it to be big enough that you won't write out of bounds. Given the downvotes, I should probably have been explicit about that)

Comment: Will that even work? Is that not guaranteed to be pretty small. [Certainly not the 999 characters that the default is]...

Comment: Unless I've missed something, won't that crash, because your empty string that you're using the internal pointer to only has 1 byte allocated to it

Comment: @Salgar, Yes, `resize` should be called if it's already been created.

Comment: Unless I"m missing something, both 1 and 2 are undefined behavior at least in C++03. In C++03 string data isn't guaranteed to be continuous. Also there's no warranty that c_str() points at writeable memory.

Comment: @SigTerm The contiguity of the memory isn't really a problem.  C++11 adopted the requirement for contiguous layout partially because that was what everyone did anyway---standardization of existing practice.

Comment: @Salgar, Mats and others, yes, you're right, I was assuming that the string would already have an appropriate size. If it doesn't, you need to explicitly resize it (and I just edited my answer to reflect that)

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 and 2 are not good, as you are not meant to alter the string you get from `std::string::c_str()` (c is for `constant`). Option 2 will need a "resize" of the string before you can use it. But I'm not sure strings are guaranteed to copy from their same buffer...

My solution would be to have:

```
char timeArray[1000];
```

(Although that is way excessive. Unless you are repeating the same format specifier several times, it's unlikely to achieve more than 100 characters, and that is very lengthy - so "sane" combinations won't reach anywhere near 1000 characters.)

Note that `timeString = timeArray` can throw an exception for `bad_alloc`, so if you want to not leak memory in that situation, you either need to use stack-based storage (as in my suggestion), a smart pointer or a try/catch block around parts of the code.

Comment: std::string won't compile in that language, will it? ;)

Comment: only if the compiler tries very hard :)

Comment: @chris You mean the `c` in `c_str`.  It is the language: you call `c_str` to get a C style string from an `std::string`.

Comment: Ok, but it's still a `const char *` that you get out of it, so it shouldn't be modified [even if it's probably POSSIBLE to modify it].

Comment: @MatsPetersson I'd go with the relatively large C style array too (but with error checking on the results of `strftime`, just in case).  Alternatively, you can use `std::vector<char>`, starting with something reasonably sized, and loop increasing its size as long as `strftime` fails.  (In pre-standard days, I had a special class for just this sort of thing.  The initial size used a C style array member, and it only shifted to dynamic allocation when you increased its size.)

Comment: @MatsPetersson You _shouldn't_ use `c_str`.  Using `&buffer[0], buffer.size()` is probably safe.  (I tend to use `std::vector<char>` for this sort of thing, because I started doing it long before it was clear that it was safe on a string.)

Answer (score 1):

The only possible solution is option 0 (though some minor adjustments can be performed). As others have pointed out, the standard says that the space returned by the `c_str()` method is not meant to be used for writing purposes, actually it is a way to allow `std::string`'s to be read by the C standard library (which is part of the C++ standard library).

The Standard reads:

> **Returns**: A pointer to the initial element of an array of length size()
>   + 1 whose first size() elements equal the corresponding elements of the string controlled by *this and whose last element is a null
>   character specified by charT().
>
> **Requires**: The program shall not
>   alter any of the values stored in the array. Nor shall the program
>   treat the returned value as a valid pointer value after any subsequent
>   call to a non-const member function of the class basic_string that
>   designates the same object as this.

So, I'd just do a quick fix to your code:

```
const char * Time::getAsFormattedString(const std::string& format)
{
    static char timeArray[256];

    std::strftime( timeArray, 256, format.c_str(), &this->time );

    return timeArray;
}
```

This makes the buffer for your method to be created in program startup, and reused continuously, so no memory errors can be expected from that side (as the heap is untouched).

The only problem is that there is space in the stack in order to create the string in which you will store the result of the function, but anyway this will happen after calling the function, the function itself won't touch the heap, and only a minimum of the stack.

In practical terms, the usefulness of the function is untouched, since there is an automatic conversion from `const char *` to `std::string`, sou you can safely call it in the usual way:

```
std::string strTime = time.getAsFormattedString( "%F %T" );
```

Hope this helps.